# AppCode Indent After Comment

Tags: objective-c, ide, appcode

I'm using AppCode for Objective-C development. It seems like one of the recent updates has changed the behavior of how indents work after a comment.

Now, when I add a comment and then hit return to enter code on the next line I get this:

[image]

Hitting return again will keep the same level of indent, and hitting delete just returns the cursor to the comment line.

What I want is:

```
// Comment
self.theCodeStartsHere;
```

which I thought used to be the default.

I have also noticed that when I try to break a statement into multiple lines they no longer line up on the colons. I'm not sure if it's related, but the behavior seemed to start around the same time.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This looks like a bug, you should report it here - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/OC

Comment: I've reported this issue to YouTrack. I'll post any updates here.

Comment: Added an answer based on my YouTrack issue.

Answer (score 1):

After posting on YouTrack, this issue seems to be fixed in [AppCode 2018.2 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/nextversion/).

**EDIT:** [YouTrack Issue Link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-17222).

Comment: Why not post the issue link here so people can go look?

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman, updated with the issue link. There's not much there, but people can take a look. At the time that I posted my question yesterday I was unaware that a new EAP version had been released.